# Prevenir populacion profunda en un Schema con referencias circulares

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Tengo el siguiente schema:

```
const Person= new Schema({

     father:   {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "Person"
     },

     childs: [{
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "Person"
     }]
})


module.exports = mongoose.model("Person", Person)
```

El siguiente paso es popular. Hago esto con un pre `find`.

```
Person.pre('find', function(next){
    this.populate('father')
    this.populate('childs')
     return next()

}
```

El problema viene cuando tengo un child apuntando a un father, y un padre apuntando a un child. Esto provoca una dependencia circular. He tratado de excluir algunos campos en child de esta manera  `this.populate('childs', '-father -childs')` pero sigue sin funcionar.

Como puedo prevenir esta populacion profunda?

## ACTUALIZACION

Actualmente resuelvo el problema desde la interfaz del usuario. Esto es con el siguiente procedimiento:

1. El usuario solicita un documento.
2. Hago mi petición al servidor express.
3. El servidor me responde con un documento no populado para estos campos.
4. Desde el cliente reviso los campos conflictivos y hago una nueva petición con ellos al servidor express.
5. El servidor me responde con uno o varios documentos no populados en los campos conflictivos.
6. Con los nuevos documentos recibidos sustituyo los campos conflictivos que se corresponden y simulo la populacion.
7. Muestro la información al usuario.

> Cualquier intento de replicar esta función pero en el servidor
>   `express` termina en un bucle infinito.

Comment: Hola @angel, cuando realizas la petición realizas filtrado de algún campo?

Comment: A qué te refieres con filtrado?

Comment: si cuando pide un documento lo filtras en base a un campo o quiere que te devuelva todo lo que tengas en la DB? Esto te lo comento porque no es lo mismo hacer un `Person.pre()` que un `Person.post()`, el primero haria una union de toda la DB.

Comment: Trato de usar la función de `populate` en cualquier situación. Si obtengo uno o todos los elementos de la `BD` datos el `pre` debe generar el query necesario para que los documentos retornen con los datos expandidos. Esto no funciona en `pos`t. Tampoco es posible modificar un documento en `post` hasta donde tengo entendido o no se como hacerlo.

Comment: ¿Has logrado probar la respuesta de @planta4? Si te funciona, ¿podrías marcar la respuesta como válida? Para cerrar la recompensa. Gracias

Comment: @MauricioContreras No he tenido tiempo de probarla. Me estoy enfocando en otro aspecto por el momento. Que procede?

Comment: Pues la probaré yo. Y aunque tengo un enfoque diferente, si la respuesta de @planta4 es válida, se lleva la recompensa. Luego de eso, publicaré mi respuesta. Saludos

Comment: Antes de publicar mi respuesta, hay una cosa que aún no me queda clara: *tengo un child apuntando a un father, y un padre apuntando a un child*. En esta frase entiendo que tienes un documento, digamos `angel`, que en su campo `father` apunta a otro documento, digamos `angelFather`, y `angelFather` tiene un elemento en su campo `childs` que apunta a `angel`. Si no es correcta esta interpretación, por favor me la aclaras. Saludos

Comment: Así como lo planteas es correcto.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Después de documentarme un poco, creo que la solución la puedes conseguir en la etapa `$graphLookup` de `aggregate` que busca de forma recursiva a través de una colección.

Para tu caso, tendría que realizarse la consulta de la siguiente forma:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { $match: {  } }, // Filtra por los campos que necesites
  {
    $graphLookup: {
      from: 'person', // Colección ha relacionar
      startWith: '$father', // Empieza a buscar sobre esta propiedad
      connectFromField: 'child', // Campo a relacionar con 'connectToField'
      connectToField: '_id',  
      maxDepth: 1, // El numero de recursividad que quieres.
      as: 'data', // El campo donde se almacenara la información
    }
  }
])
```

Al poder indicar el numero de profundidad/recursividad no llegaras al bucle infinito que te esta ocurriendo.

Te paso un par de links que me han ayudado a entender `$graphLookup` que sabia que existía pero nunca me ha salido la ocasión de utilizarla y creo que es un buen caso para ello.

[API MongoDB](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/graphLookup/)

[Un buen ejemplo para entender $graphLookup](https://thecodebarbarian.com/a-nodejs-perspective-on-mongodb-34-graphlookup.html)

Aun así, si no te ha podido ayudar esto espero que te de alguna idea para solucionarlo.

Un saludo

Comment: No he tenido tiempo de probar esto pero lo veo con mucho optimismo. En cuanto lo prueba comento por acá los resultados.

Answer (score 0):

Aunque ya tienes una respuesta que es válida, intentaré usar una aproximación diferente para resolver el problema.

**PROBLEMA**

El problema lo tienes cuando intentas realizar un proceso `middleware` de [MongooseJS](https://mongoosejs.com/) conocido como [`pre hook`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html#pre).

Una de las cosas que debemos tomar en cuenta a la hora de realizar operaciones de este tipo es entender lo que sucede en el proceso.

Cada vez que se llama al método [`populate`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html) en esta parte previa a la consulta, se realiza una modificación al objeto `this`, que en este caso representa un objeto de tipo [`Query`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/query.html). En dicha modificación, se incluyen los campos a ser poblados.

Todo esto está muy bien, sin embargo el problema se presenta debido a que los campos a ser poblados son de la misma colección.

Por cada campo a ser poblado, se realiza una llamada al método `find` para realizar la búsqueda de los datos de dicho campo, y dado que hemos establecido un `pre hook` para dicho método en nuestro esquema, se ejecutará nuevamente nuestro `middleware` que buscará poblar los campos que hemos solicitado para dicha colección.

Si tenemos `n` generaciones emparentadas por un único campo, se realizarán `n + 1` llamadas al `middleware pre`.

Supongamos que tenemos 2 documentos:

```js
// angelFather:
{
  _id: ObjectId(5de6c26911859266abd0a209)
  name: 'Papa de Angel',
  childs: [ObjectId('5de6c26911859266abd0a20a')]
}

//angel
{
  _id: ObjectId(5de6c26911859266abd0a20a)
  name: 'Angel',
  father: ObjectId('5de6c26911859266abd0a209'),
  childs: []
}
```

Tenemos sólo 1 generación relacionada con 'Papa de Angel', ya que sólo tiene un campo `childs` y no posee un campo `father`. El campo `childs` tiene un valor que apunta a 'Angel'. El documento 'Angel' tiene un campo `childs` con un `Array` vacío, y un campo `father` que apunta a 'Papa de Angel'.

Si hacemos un llamado a `populate('childs')` para el documento 'Papa de Angel' mediante un `pre hook`, se realizará una búsqueda de los documentos del campo `childs`. Esta búsqueda se hará usando el método `find`. Y ya que hemos establecido un `pre hook` para el método `find`, a los documentos encontrados (aquellos cuya referencia aparece en el campo `childs` de 'Papa de Angel'), se les aplicará también el método `populate` sobre el campo `childs`. Como 'Angel' no tiene hijos, la búsqueda se detiene allí. Dando como resultado que se habrá ejecutado 2 veces nuestro `pre hook`, para 1 generación emparentada con el documento 'Papa de Angel' en el campo `childs`.

Esto nos da una idea de la forma en que funciona el método `populate` en una instancia `pre hook`.

En tu caso, no sólo estás llamando al método `populate` para el campo `childs` sino que lo haces también para el campo `father`, y es eso lo que provoca el bucle infinito.

Tomemos el mismo caso anterior,

1. Primero se realiza el proceso de `populate` para los campos `father` y `childs` del documento 'Papa de Angel'
2. 'Papa de Angel' no tiene un campo `father`, la búsqueda sobre este campo finaliza allí.
3. Se inicia la búsqueda sobre el campo `childs`, para ello se llama al método `find` sobre los elementos del campo `childs`.
4. Se dispara nuevamente nuestro `middleware` para *poblar* los campos `childs` y `father` del documento 'Angel'.
5. La búsqueda sobre el campo `childs` de 'Angel' termina allí ('Angel' no tiene hijos).
6. Se genera una búsqueda sobre el documento relacionado en el campo `father`, el cual es 'Papa de Angel'.
7. Se dispara nuevamente nuestro `middleware` ya que la búsqueda se realiza usando el método `find`.
8. Se genera un proceso de `populate` sobre los campos `father` y `childs` del documento 'Papa de Angel'. Estamos nuevamente en donde iniciamos (punto 1).

Es por esto que se produce el bucle infinito.

**SOLUCIÓN**

La solución parece tonta, sin embargo tiene su razón.

No uses un `pre hook` para hacer `populate` de documentos cuya referencia apunta a la misma colección. El motivo te lo acabo de explicar. Estarías usando recursos innecesariamente, al realizar repetidas llamadas a la base de datos para obtener 1 sólo dato necessario y `n` datos innecesarios. Ya vimos que si tienes `n` documentos enlazados sobre la misma colección, se harán `n+1` peticiones a la base de datos para *poblar* los campos necesarios.

Como sólo te interesa 1 nivel de búsqueda (buscar sólo los datos del documento o documentos cuya referencia aparece en el campo `father` y en el campo `childs`), el proceso de `populate` debes hacerlo sobre el Objeto Query devuelto por tu consulta `find`.

Por ejemplo:

```js
async function(req, res) {
  const persons = await Person.find({}).populate('father').populate('childs');
  persons.forEach(person => {
    console.log(`Name: ${person.name}`);
    if(person.father) {
      console.log('Father:');
      console.log(person.father);
    }
    if(person.childs.length) {
      console.log('Childs:');
      person.childs.forEach((child, i) => {
        console.log(`Child ${i+1}:`);
        console.log(child);
      });
    }
  });
}
```

Si corremos el código anterior sobre el documento 'Papa de Angel', el resultado obtenido sería:

```js
Name: Papa de Angel
Childs:
Child 1:
{
  childs: [],
  _id: 5de6c26911859266abd0a20a,
  name: 'Angel',
  father: 5de6c26911859266abd0a209,
  __v: 0
}
```

Como 'Papa de Angel' no posee un campo `father`, el mismo es omitido en la salida por consola, pero el campo `childs` ha sido *poblado* con los datos del documento 'Angel'.

Ahora, dirás, *pero es que primero se hizo `populate` al campo `father` y no al campo `childs`*. Pues resulta que el orden no afecta el resultado.

Por lo tanto, las siguientes líneas son todas equivalentes:

```js
const personas = await Person.find({_id: ObjectId('5de6c26911859266abd0a209')}).populate('childs').populate('father');
// es equivalente a:
const personas = await Person.find({_id: ObjectId('5de6c26911859266abd0a209')}).populate('father').populate('childs');
// es equivalente a:
const personas = await Person.find({_id: ObjectId('5de6c26911859266abd0a209')}).populate('childs father');
// es equivalente a:
const personas = await Person.find({_id: ObjectId('5de6c26911859266abd0a209')}).populate('father childs');
```

**¿Qué cambia con respecto a hacer el `populate` en un `pre hook`?**

Pues en primer lugar, el método `find` devuelve un Objeto `Query` cuyos documentos tienen un campo `father` y un campo `childs` que no han sido *poblados*, a dichos campos se les aplica el proceso de `populate`, que devolverá solamente los valores de los documentos (de la misma colección en este caso) que coincidan con sus respectivas referencias, y el proceso culmina allí. Es decir, aunque dichos documentos *poblados* contienen a su vez campos `father` y `childs`, no es sobre ellos que se está aplicando un proceso de `populate`. Además, sus campos respectivos serían campos anidados dentro del campo `father` y `childs` originales.

Por último, si te parece engorroso escribir las llamadas al método `populate` directamente después de la llamada al método `find`, o si por alguna razón quieres centralizar este proceso, puedes escribir tu propia función. Por ejemplo:

```js
/*!
 * Retorna un objeto Query.
 *
 * @param {Object} Model el Modelo sobre el cual realizar la búsqueda
 * @param {Array} paths array con los nombres de los campos a ser poblados
 * @param {Array} fields array con los nombres de los campos a devolver en los documentos poblados
 * @return {Object} un Objeto Query con los documentos poblados
 */
const populate = async (Model, paths, fields) => {
  paths = paths.join(' ');
  fields = fields.join(' ');
  try {
    return await Model.find().populate(paths, fields);
  } catch(ex) {
    console.log(ex.message);
    throw ex;
  }
}
```

Luego podrías usarlo en tu código de la siguiente forma:

```js
async function(req, res) {
  try {
    const persons = await populate(Person, ['father', 'childs'], ['_id', 'name']);
    // hacemos cosas con el resultado
  }
  catch(e) {
    // manejamos el error
  }
}
```

Espero que esto aclare tu duda de porqué estabas cayendo en un bucle infinito al usar un `pre hook` para *poblar* tus campos con referencia a la misma colección.